# Multiple hop NX connection

Tags: linux, centos, nx, freenx

I'm managing a set of servers on a private network with one facing the internet (ie. one public ip). Soon I'll need to start working remotely, and I'll need access to some graphical programs. I'd like to use freeNX, because I've read that it's protocol is much quicker than normal X11 forwarding and I already have it set up on my internet facing machine. I'd like to be able to forward NX connections through multiple computers in the network such that from my remote computer I can connect to any computer in the internal network.

'*remote machine*' --> '*internet facing machine*' --> '*arbitrary internal machine*'

I know that there are at least a couple methods to accomplish something similar:

1. Modify the server's node.conf to automatically forward connections to a second machine.
2. Setup ssh tunnels on the internet facing computer.

I don't particularly like either of these. I don't like number one, because it only allows me to specify one computer to connect to. I don't like number two, because I don't have authority to open ports to the internet (ie. some admin above me does that).

Is there another way to forward NX connections?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use a mix of NX and X11 forwarding. I can NX to my internet facing machine and then forward X11 through ssh from other machines on the network. The performance is much better than forwarding X11 over the internet.